# CorelDRAW VBA Text Manipulation

Tags: vba, scripting, coreldraw

I want to write a VBA script for CorelDRAW to assign an Object Style to various text strings within a Paragraph Frame.
Something like (psuedo code example):

```
- move cursor forward to next Start of Line
- select text from cursor to next Tab character
- set selected text to Object Style 1
```

I have not been able to find any examples or doco of using scripting to do text manipulation in CorelDRAW. I'd be happy to do it using Javascript (available in CDGS 2019) if that is easier.

The way I see this script working is that I would manually position the text cursor at the start of the paragraph frame, hit a shortcut key to invoke the script, and then repeat until all desired changes are made. Possibly add looping at a later step.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: 1. Style applied only to whole paragraph! Find tab character change nothing.
2. I dont know how find position of your cursor in paragraph text. Can select only first paragraph, second paragraph, ....

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ivan.  An Object Style can be applied to text within a paragraph. It does not have to be a whole paragraph (CD 2019). I can also achieve what I want by applying a specific colour to selected text - it does not have to be done using styles.

Comment: What mean "set selected text to **Object Style 1**"?

Comment: I think you can find and select text from start line(paragraph mark) to tab symbol only from whole text frame, not from a part follow your cursor place. Then assign any properties to this selection.

Comment: To find position first start line in selected text frame `Dim t As TextCharacters
     Set t = ActiveShape.Text.Story.Characters
    For i = 1 To t.Count
    s = t.Item(i)
   If Asc(s) = 13 Then Exit For
   Next i` Result is in variable i

Comment: To find position tab character after find start line can use function `j = ActiveShape.Text.Find(Chr(9), False, i + 1, False)`

Comment: Object Style 1 refers to an object style that I have defined to change the colour of whatever is selected. Object Styles can assign attributes (eg colour, bold, font size etc) to any text within a paragraph text object.

Comment: While I use style on corelx3 it apply on whole text frame, not on selection. In new version may be another behaviour. I explain how find part of text. Then select it and apply style